# Monitoring input field change jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to detect whent i increment/decrement input value? The following code does not work for me(Using jquery 1.8)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("input[id=count]").change(function(){
        alert($(this).val());
      });
    });
```

```html
<input type="number" id="count" value="1">
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Use [**`input`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) event using [**`.on`**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method.

*The `DOM input event` is fired synchronously when the value of an `<input>` or `<textarea>` element is changed.*

`change` event on `input` type `number/text` is invoked when focus of the element is lost

***Note:*** `$("#count")` is more appropriate selector([`ID selector`](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)) than using [`Attribute Equals Selector [name=”value”]`](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) selector

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#count").on('input', function() {
    console.log($(this).val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="count" value="1">
```